# Jquery mobile sub page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When using Jquery mobile and you navigate to a sub page in a single page application via an anchor tag, the url updates to be .com#someid

When the user refreshes this page, I need some Javascript to execute as if the user had navigated to that page... ie, reload some ajax data.

How is this typically handled?

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage"  data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="content" class="contentcontainer"><a     href="#subpage">some content</a></div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="subpage"  data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="content" class="contentcontainer">some content</div>
</div>

<script>
  function loadContentForSubpage(){ ...}
</script>
```

I only want the loadContentForSubpage to run when that page loads, or when the user refreshes the page that has #subpage

Comment: Where is your code? This is not a site where we write code for you, This is only a site where we help you with errors, problems and misunderstandings.

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="homepage"  data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="content" class="contentcontainer"><a     href="#subpage">some content</a></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="subpage"  data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="content" class="contentcontainer">some content</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function loadContentForSubpage(){ ...}
    </script>

I only want the loadContentForSubpage to run when that page loads, or when the user refreshes the page that has #subpage

Comment: Edit your question and add that there @Nathan Leggat

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this..

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.hash === "#someid") {
        //do something
    }
});
```